# Where is program running when shared through a folder?

Tags: windows, share, remote-server

I do have a (server) Windows machine running a Java app and a DB. The Java app has an UI and it is wrapped in an .exe. Now I share the .exe's folder with client machines. From such client machines I click the .exe, where does the program run? If it is running on the remote machine how can it be that I see the UI on my machine? What's happen when many client users click on the .exe contemporarly?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think it gets executed on the client/local machine (local copy).